# lookup command gets unknown flag error

Tags: 18.04

I'm getting

```
lookup:unknown flag "-f"
```

error when I use this code

```
lookup -f test.txt<test1.txt>test11.txt.
```

If I don't use the flag I get `ioctl TCGETA` error. I am getting the same error on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS.

Any feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from `man lookup`

```
The following flags are supported:

   -help
      Reports a short help message and exits.

   -write  Creates index files for the named files and exits. No
      startup file is read.

   -euc
      Sets the input and output encoding method to EUC (currently the default).  Exactly the same as the¡Èencoding euc¡Écommand.

   -jis
      Sets the input and output encoding method to JIS.  Exactly the same as the¡Èencoding jis¡Écommand.

   -sjis
      Sets the input and output encoding method to Shift-JIS.  Exactly the same as the¡Èencoding sjis¡Écommand.

   -v -version
      Prints the version string and exits.

   -norc
      Indicates that the startup file should not be read.

   -rc file
      The named file is used as the startup file, rather than the default¡È~/.lookup¡É.  It is an error for the file not to exist.

   -percent num
      When an index is built, letters that appear on more than num percent (default 50) of the lines are elided from the index.  The thought is  that  if  a  search
      will  have to check most of the lines in a file anyway, one may as well save the large amount of space in the index file needed to represent that information,
      and the time/space tradeoff shifts, as the indexing of oft-occurring letters provides a diminishing return.

      Smaller indexes can be made by using a smaller number.

   -noindex
      Indicates that any files loaded via the command line should not be loaded with any precomputed index, but recalculated on the fly

   -verbose
      Has metric tons of stats spewed whenever an index is created.

   -port ###
      For the (undocumented) server configuration only, tells which port to listen on.
```

There's no `-f` flag